# Relationships and where clauses?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
**galleries**

id
location
open_to_public

**pictures**
id
title
published

**gallery_picture**
gallery_id
picture_id
```

Here's my model for galleries:

```
class Galleries extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'galleries';

public function pictures(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('pictures', 'gallery_picture', 'gallery_id', 'picture_id');

}
```

I'm trying to select a gallery (id, location) and get it's related pictures (id, title).

To start with I've tried this but it seems to return a huge amount of data, im not sure if I'm doing it correct?

```
$this->mGalleries = new Galleries;
return $this->mGalleries->pictures();
```

What I want to also do is add some constraints to the query, I understand I can do it like:

```
public function scopePublic()
{
        return $query->where('open_to_public','=',1);
}
```

Then:
    return $this->mGalleries->pictures()->public();

But I have yet to implement this correctly. Could someone point me in the right direction.

I want to get gallery.id, gallery.location and all of that galleries pictures where gallery.open_to_public = 1 and to only get pictures that published = 1.

Also I would like to get all of the galleries that are relevant to the above conditions and not just a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the specific error you're receiving it's hard to say exactly what's going on her,e but one thing that jumped out at me from your code samples is that you don't accept the `$query` as a parameter to your scope method. Try this code instead:

```
public function scopePublic($query)
{
        return $query->where('open_to_public','=',1);
}
```

Additionally to that it looks like you're calling your scoped function on the wrong object. From your description you need something like the following set up:

- `Gallery` (model)

  - `scopePublic($query)`
- `Picture` (model)

  - `scopePublished($query)`

Also, you can only get the pictures of a single gallery, not all galleries in one go. So you can't use `Gallery::all()->pictures` as you might expect but instead you have to do your own collection building.

Your final code will end up being something like the following:

```
// empty collection to store all our pictures
$pictures = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

// get all galleries open to the public
$galleries = Gallery::public()->get();

// for each gallery, get its pictures and add it to the collection
$galleries->each(function ($gallery) use ($pictures) {
    $pictures->merge($gallery->pictures()->published()->get());
});
```

However, there are a few different ways you could do this. You might find that preloading your relations helps with the database queries too (look up Eloquent's `with()`, and see if there's a way to pass your scope call in there somehow). Alternatively, if Eloquent's syntax is a little too verbose, you could try using the `DB` class and joins manually.

Also, sorry if that code is buggy, it's untested but should give you at least a grounding of how to go about solving this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having toruble getting out the basics: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Galleries)#196 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Which as I understand it, imeans it's empty, but I have data in my database.

Comment: Called via: $this->mGalleries->pictures()->get();

Comment: Yup, but as I said you can't call a belongsToMany relationship directly on the class - you need an instance.

Comment: When you call $this->mGalleries->pictures() you're trying to say "get me all pictures associated to {i don't care which gallery}" but you need to say "get me all pictures associated to {a given gallery}" - so you need something like `$this->mGalleries->find(1)->pictures()` - that gets all pictures associated to gallery with id 1.

Comment: When you call $this->mGalleries->pictures() you're not using a real instance, you're using an empty instance of the Galleries model, so it gets all pictures associated to no gallery (there's no gallery id, so it can't get the associated pictures as it doesn't know what to look for). You'll likely fine, if you logged the SQL for `$this->mGalleries->pictures()` that you get something like ``SELECT * FROM `pictures` LEFT JOIN `gallery_picture` ON ... WHERE `gallery_picture`.`gallery_id` IS NULL`` which gets you a nice empty result.

Comment: I see, thanks very much. how do you log the SQL btw?

Comment: There are a few ways (as ever). You can see the SQL generated for a given query with `->toSql()` on the `Builder` instance: `$this->mGalleries->pictures()->toSql()` or you can log all database queries by binding a closure to the Eloquent `illuminate.query` event: `Event::listen('illuminate.query', function ($sql) { \Log::debug($sql); });`